# Bitmaps Click Listener

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I am developing an application in which i have to draw multiple bitmaps and combine the to create a proper shape and i have to implement click listeners on all images separately. I can do this with image views and also by drawing bitmaps on canvas but how to implement this by coding i have no idea

the image is like this

[image]

this image is consist of many small images and they are combined to make this full image

Answer (score 0):

override this method and identify the touch position and do what ever you want...

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: at first i have to draw this image

Comment: if you have the drawable resources then prefer to draw the layout using canvas, in that Path and Paint are more helpful to you...